# javascript or htaccess rewrite url

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

Recently i walked through many `.htaccess` rewrite url(user-friendly url) tutorials.that is to write url like following.

```
domain.com/product/item1
```

I want to know is there any way to do this type of stuff with javascript?
May be its not possible
but the following kind of stuff may be possible with javascript

```
domain.com/index.php/my-product
```

example webbsite:http://10deals.in/index.php/beauty-spas

I tried to google this stuff but failed.plz link any tutorial or explain something about this.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: ```.htaccess``` works on a server level (backend) in JS on the client side and the URL rewrite is transparent to it, JS does not know anything about it and cannot change it (easily)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Your url will always try to load a file from that path, since JS only runs as soon as it's loaded, client-side.
By then, a redirect would be a bit pointless.

Comment: is this type of url `domain.com/index.php/my-product` is possible with `JS`.

my-products is my query string

Comment: No. In your case, JavaScript is a client-side language (Since you're using php server side). What you're trying to do is something that can't be done client-side.